# python import vs from ... import in flask application

Tags: python

I have application built with flask framework Flask==0.12.2, python 2.7.13

There is one problem with using import.

I have something like this:

```
import foo.bar as bar
```

At the beginning it was working fine. Later it stopped working and showed error as below.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attibute 'bar'
```

This becomes working after I changed import to:

```
from foo.bar import bar
```

The problem fixed but I don't understand why import stopped working and from ... import worked.

Comment: Without seeing your code, and specifically, your file layout, we can't say. You've moved some modules/files or functions around causing this, because the two imports are not equivalene.t

Answer (score 2):

The two are not the same.

When you do `import foo.bar as bar`, your `bar` is `foo.bar`.

When you do `from foo.bar import bar`, your `bar` is `foo.bar.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

As said, both the imports are not same.

`import foo.bar as bar` imports `bar` from `foo.bar`

`from foo.bar import bar` imports `bar` from `foo.bar.bar`

To do an import in python, there are few conditions:

1. There must be an `__init__.py` to specify the folder as a module.
2. Classes cannot be directly imported using `.(dot)`.
3. Modules can be imported either using `.(dot)` or with `from` keyword.

For example,

Consider a class `SampleClass` inside `foo.bar`, it can be imported only with `from foo.bar import SampleClass`, and `import foo.bar.SampleClass` will throw `ImportError`.

However, `bar` can be imported either with `import foo.bar as bar` or `from foo import bar`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without seeing the code, but I think the issue is similar to this:

> You have a package called **foo**, and inside that package you have a
>   module called **bar**. Inside module **bar**, there's an attribute called **bar**.

All **import foo.bar as bar** does is importing the **bar** module, to access the attribute **bar**, you need to call **bar.bar**

```
import foo.bar as bar

print(bar.bar()) # assumes attribute bar is a method
```

**from foo.bar import bar** makes the attribute **bar** available without its **package prefix**, so it can be used as follow:

```
from foo.bar import bar

print(bar())
```